# Highcharts column stacked drilldown - hover highlights wrong column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Have a chart done using Highcharts. It is a stacked drilldown column type. Its purpose is to display over 12month or 30 days, the number of positive/negative entries.

At the moment when someone hovers a column or section of a column a different part of another column is being highlighted. Tried to debug it, but did not get close to the source of the problem to give you some more indications.

Any help towards where to look or how to solve this is greatly appreciated.
Please find below the jsfiddle and a SS of the issue. 
If there is anything else I can provide, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marinr/L9gyLgrv/3/)

```
var valuesArrayMonth = [{
    name: 'HELPFUL',
    color: '#34b9c7',
    data: [{
        name: 'JAN',
        y: 5,
        drilldown: 'JAN'
    }, {
        name: 'FEB',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: 'FEB'
    }, {
        name: 'MAR',
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'MAR'
    }, {
        name: 'APR',
        y: 9,
        drilldown: 'APR'
    }, {
        name: 'MAY',
        y: 25,
        drilldown: 'MAY'
    }, {
        name: 'JUN',
        y: 34,
        drilldown: 'JUN'
    }, {
        name: 'JUL',
        y: 72,
        drilldown: 'JUL'
    }, {
        name: 'AUG',
        y: 22,
        drilldown: 'AUG'
    }, {
        name: 'SEP',
        y: 34,
        drilldown: 'SEP'
    }, {
        name: 'OCT',
        y: 54,
        drilldown: 'OCT'
    }, {
        name: 'NOV',
        y: 31,
        drilldown: 'NOV'
    }, {
        name: 'DEC',
        y: 27,
        drilldown: 'DEC'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'NOT HELPFUL',
    color: '#ae0700',
    data: [{
        name: 'JAN',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: 'JAN2'
    }, {
        name: 'FEB',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: 'FEB2'
    }, {
        name: 'MAR',
        y: 1,
        drilldown: 'MAR2'
    }, {
        name: 'APR',
        y: 1,
        drilldown: 'APR2'
    }, {
        name: 'MAY',
        y: 5,
        drilldown: 'MAY2'
    }, {
        name: 'JUN',
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'JUN2'
    }, {
        name: 'JUL',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: 'JUL2'
    }, {
        name: 'AUG',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: 'AUG2'
    }, {
        name: 'SEP',
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'SEP2'
    }, {
        name: 'OCT',
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'OCT2'
    }, {
        name: 'NOV',
        y: 1,
        drilldown: 'NOV2'
    }, {
        name: 'DEC',
        y: 7,
        drilldown: 'DEC2'
    }]
}];
    var valuesArrayDays = [{
      id: 'JAN',
      name: 'JAN',
      data: [
          ['1', 4],
          ['2', 2],
          ['3', 1],
          ['4', 2],
          ['5', 1]
      ]
  },{
      id: 'JAN2',
      name: 'JAN',
      data: [
          ['1', 3],
          ['2', 5],
          ['3', 6],
          ['4', 2],
          ['5', 2]
      ]
  },{
      id: 'MAR',
      name: 'MAR',
      data: [
          ['1', 3],
          ['2', 5],
          ['3', 6],
          ['4', 2],
          ['5', 2]
      ]
  },{
      id: 'MAR2',
      name: 'MAR',
      data: [
          ['1', 3],
          ['2', 5],
          ['3', 6],
          ['4', 2],
          ['5', 2]
      ]
  }];


$(function() {

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: null,
                zoomType: 'xy',  
                spacingLeft: 70,
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'BigNoodleThing'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                crosshair:{
                    color: '#fdd54c'
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                opposite:true,
                gridLineColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)", 
            },
            credits:{
                enabled:false
            },
            legend:{
                enabled:false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true, 
                            color: '#343434'
                        }
                    } 
                },
                column: {
                    stacking: 'percent'
                }
            },  
            tooltip: {

                shared: true,
                color: '#ffffff',
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#ffffff', 
                borderRadius:0,
                shadow:false,
                borderWidth:0,
                style: {
                    padding: 12,
                    fontSize: '14px', 
                }, 
                shape:'square',
                useHTML: true,
            },

            series: valuesArrayMonth,
            drilldown: {
                activeAxisLabelStyle: { 
                    textDecoration: 'none',
                    color: '#343434', 
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    fontWeight: 'normal'        
                },
                series: valuesArrayDays
            }
  })
});
```

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPnp.jpg)

Comment: It does not display the other colomn. If you look closely, your hover over tooltip is placed on the left of the each colomn. For the first 2 colomns if the colomn does not have enough place to show the tooltip on the left  so it moves it on the right in the middle of the page. You need to alter the built in code that handles the hover tooltip in highcharts in a way that if the colomn is to the far left of the page then it needs to show  the tooltip to the right of the same colomn if not enough space.

Comment: The tooltip is not the problem. Use case: Hover over 'FEB' column blue section, then hover over 'JAN' column blue section => you will see that when switching to 'JAN' column from 'FEB' column  it highlights 'JAN' blue section and 'FEB' red section as selected (this is the bug that needs fixing)

Comment: Hmm. Now i see the issue. Let me check and get back to you with an answer.

Comment: It's a bug - see the ticket on github https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6586 - it is fixed on master branch https://jsfiddle.net/L9gyLgrv/11/

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you would like to post your comment as an answer